# Plug-in Conflict: Art Direction and Super Cache

Tags: plugins, cache

I use [Art Direction](http://noel.io/wordpress-art-direction-plugin/) plugin to create customized posts sometimes. I also want to use [Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) plugin for traffic spikes. However I've found that once you have Supercache activated Art Direction plugin no longer works, due to the way Supercache renders your html.

Is there anyway to get around this? Or is there another caching plugin that works with Art Direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to currently get around this is to not directly use Art Direction but replicate that functionality yourself.

There are a few pages that talk you through doing that:

- http://digwp.com/2010/02/custom-css-per-post/
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-art-direction-conflict-with-wp-super-cache

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks. I also use custom fields for post specific css. I wonder if there's another caching plugin i can use that doesn't conflict with Art Direction.